# MapView in iOS6 crashes when zooming map

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocation

I'm trying to span a map to the center of two coordinates. It worked fine on previous versions of iOS, but now suddenly, I get this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:nan, nan span:nan, nan>'
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D savedCoordinate;
        savedCoordinate.latitude = [userDef doubleForKey:@"savedCoordinate-latitude"];
        savedCoordinate.longitude = [userDef doubleForKey:@"savedCoordinate-longitude"];

        savedPosition = savedCoordinate;

        CLLocationDistance visibleDistance = 100;
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(savedCoordinate, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
        [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you the problem: The coordinate you're specifying contains **nan** ("not a number") rather than a regular number.

If you log your coordinate pieces you should be able to find out the specifics. In particular, I'd be looking at `savedCoordinate.latitude` and `savedCoordinate.longitude`. Perhaps you're storing a string in the user defaults instead of a number? If the key doesn't exist in the user defaults, these should be 0 rather than nan.

See also:

- [Wikipedia: NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Comment: [userDef setDouble:location.latitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-latitude"];
[userDef setDouble:location.longitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-longitude"];
[userDef setBool:YES forKey:@"savedCoordinate-exist"]; , am i supposed to store something else instead of a double?

Comment: What's `savedCoordinate` look like before it's passed into `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`?